# Amazon GuardDuty: How to filter out Finding Type?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

I am testing out [Amazon GuardDuty](https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/) and see that I am able to search the results by [finding type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/guardduty_finding-types.html) effectively, but how can I remove a finding type to show all the results except that single type (other than filtering for every other finding type except the one I am unconcerned with)?

For example, let's say I wanted to show all findings except for the `Recon:EC2/PortProbeUnprotectedPort` results.

Alternatively, if I can only filter out results by searching for everything except the undesired result is there a method to search the finding types using a regex?   For example searching for something similar to: `Finding type: Trojan:EC2/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to view a certain type of findings, you can do so by creating a filter and selecting [auto-archive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/guardduty_findings.html#guardduty_filter-findings) option. I'm not sure about the regex but I think it is not possible, will test and let you know.